# Jquery .change() on select causes Foundation Section to disappear until window is resized

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation as a framework, and jQuery to show/hide a `<div>` containing a Foundation based on a `<select>` dropdown box. The jQuery is pretty simple:

```
$(document).ready(
  function()
 {
  $('.dropdown').hide();
  $('#divsp1').show();
  $('select').data("previous-value", $('select').val());
  $('select').change(function() {
    var previousValue = $(this).data("previous-value");
    $('#divsp' + previousValue).hide();
    $('#divsp' + $(this).val()).show();
    $(this).data("previous-value", $(this).val());
  });
}
);
```

Simplified HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="divsp1" class="dropdown">
  <div class="section-container auto" data-section>
    <section class="active">
      <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel1">Section 1</a></p>
      <div class="content" data-section-content>
        <p>Content of section 1.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel2">Section 2</a></p>
      <div class="content" data-section-content>
        <p>Content of section 2.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="divsp2" class="dropdown">
  <div class="section-container auto" data-section>
    <section class="active">
      <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel1">Section 1</a></p>
      <div class="content" data-section-content>
        <p>Content of section 3.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel2">Section 2</a></p>
      <div class="content" data-section-content>
        <p>Content of section 4.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

<form autocomplete="off">
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Selecting anything other than the initial value causes the selected `<div>` to disappear. It only reappears if the window is resized. I've also captured this behavior [in a video here](http://youtu.be/Ij90NYoxp20).

Once the window is resized, the jQuery select functions as desired. I'm seeing this issue in Firefox and Chrome, both on Windows and Mac OS X.

<strike>Is there something wrong with my jQuery that is causing this issue?</strike>

## EDIT

I narrowed this down to an issue with Foundation and jQuery. [I created a site with vanilla Foundation](http://thistestsite.nfshost.com) and tried to do the same thing: `<div>` containing Foundation Panels that are switchable via jQuery. No luck. I'll have to find another way to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Your code has no bug up to the part you shown here. Must be some other part conflicts. You can check how your code works here.  http://jsfiddle.net/AhL6P/

Comment: I think either because of css or other code portions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't read the documentation thoroughly enough. Adding one simple line to the .js file fixes it:

```
$(this).foundation('section', 'reflow');
```

I found the line in the [Section documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/section.html).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check by replacing with this one..

```
please this line......
$('.subProductBox#div' + $(this).val()).show();

with this........

$('#div'+ $(this).val()).show();

I hope this will be helpful
```

Comment: Nope, this doesn't do anything.